# How to impose custom style to the edges of a graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

We construct a graph as the following.

```
node = {11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16};
edges = {11 -> 14, 11 -> 16, 12 -> 16, 12 -> 15, 13 -> 15, 13 -> 16, 
         14 -> 16, 14 -> 15, 15 -> 16, 15 -> 13, 16 -> 15, 16 -> 14};
vertexposition = {{6.51493919050084`, 44.04756585632944`}, 
    {75.59445680043342`, 50.47455242214042`}, 
    {87.32825501506514`, 13.395648943951699`}, 
    {28.795707353492418`, 3.420138063734413`}, 
    {60.729164933330765`, 16.915777496473908`}, 
    {51.85158892659126`, 25.803692768150313`}};
Show[
    Graph[node, edges, VertexCoordinates -> vertexposition, 
          VertexSize -> {"Scaled", .02},VertexLabels -> "Name"],
    Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> True, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

1. Now in the above graph how can I can control the size of the `Arrowheads` and thickness/color/opacity of the lines?
2. Is there any options that I can use to make the graph aesthetically more eye catching (sorry for using a qualitative term!)?
3. Without using `Show` can I display the frame and the axes values directly in a `Graph`?

Comment: Have you checked the docs?   There are really so many examples there of exactly what you are asking for.  Please do try to find the solution before you post such a question, and do describe what you tried so far and why it wasn't good enough.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For the first part of your question you can use a custom function for the `EdgeShapeFunction` option of `Graph`:

Let

```
   edgeshape[e_, ___] := {Arrowheads[Large], Red, Thick, Arrow[e, 0.2]}
```

and use as

```
 Show[Graph[node, edges, VertexCoordinates -> vertexposition, 
 VertexSize -> {"Scaled", .02}, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
 EdgeShapeFunction -> edgeshape], Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> True, 
 ImageSize -> 600]
```

to get

[image]

**`Graph` also takes `Graphics` options**, so you can use

```
 Graph[node, edges, VertexCoordinates -> vertexposition, 
 VertexSize -> {"Scaled", .02}, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
 EdgeShapeFunction -> edgeshape, Axes -> True, Ticks -> Automatic, 
 TicksStyle -> Directive[Orange, 12], PlotRangePadding -> .1, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

to get

[image]

**Update:** Using Szabolcs's revised answer, adding `Frame->True, FrameTicks->All` to options

```
 Graph[node, edges, VertexCoordinates -> vertexposition, 
 VertexSize -> {"Scaled", .02}, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
 EdgeShapeFunction -> edgeshape, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
 FrameTicks -> All, FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Orange, 12]]!
```

[image]

You can also define your custom  tick function. e.g.

```
 ticks[min_, max_] := 
 Table[If[EvenQ[i], {i, i, {.01, 0}, Red}, {i, i, {.01, 0},  Blue}], {i, Floor[min],   Floor[max], 10}]
```

and use it with `FrameTicks`

```
 Graph[node, edges, VertexCoordinates -> vertexposition, 
 VertexSize -> {"Scaled", .02}, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
  EdgeShapeFunction -> edgeshape, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
 FrameTicks -> ticks, FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Orange, 12], 
 PlotRangePadding -> 5, ImagePadding -> 30]
```

to get

[image]

From the above answers to your first and third questions, you should be glad that i am not attempting to answer your second question.

Answer (score 9):

1. Use `EdgeStyle` with `Arrowheads`, `Thickness`, colour specifications, `Opacity`.
2. Please see http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/GraphStylingAndLabeling.html
3. `Graph` will take the same options as `Graphics` so you can use `Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> All`

The docs have plenty of examples.